# split values in qlikview and how this values can be filtred

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I want to spit an expression in qlikview, I have this values:

```
     Column1
 564564/455654
 546546/POMLK21435
 458798/454687/P44545
```

I want to pick in each line the number which is contain 6 num like this bellow:

```
    Column1               Column2        Column3
  564564/455654           564564         455654
  546546/POMLK21435       546546
  458798/454687/P44545    458798         454687
```

How can I do that please

Thank you for your help

Comment: try to use the command subfield (https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/12.0/Subsystems/Client/Content/Scripting/StringFunctions/SubField.htm?q=subfield) together with and "if" and/or "alt" to check that it is a number

for your case : alt(subfield (Column1,'/',1) ,subfield (Column1,'/',2),subfield (Column1,'/',3))....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at subfield() and isnum(). Something like

```
If(isnum(Subfield([Column1],'/',1)),Subfield([Column1],'/',1),Null()) as [Column2],
If(isnum(Subfield([Column1],'/',2)),Subfield([Column1],'/',1),Null()) as [Column3]
```

would probably work for you.

Comment: Nice. Also for arbitrary number of "/" in Column1 Nina probably wants to use substringcount() and loop through them with a for loop.